# How to install PeerTube on Debian 11 (bullseye)

Tags: linux, debian, dns, nginx

On Raspberry Pi OS I've followed PeerTube install steps from the docs except for the Webserver steps. So up until and including the PeerTube configuration and the systemd configuration. I've opened the ports in the router `NAT/PAT/CGNAT settings`. I've created a DNS in https://www.duckdns.org/. And now I'm seeing a nginx welcome message in the domain. **What are the steps that I have to take to finish configuring PeerTube?**

In the webserver steps there are some commands that replace some variables into a file but the variables are empty:

```
sudo sed -i 's/${WEBSERVER_HOST}/[peertube-domain]/g' /etc/nginx/sites-available/peertube
sudo sed -i 's/${PEERTUBE_HOST}/127.0.0.1:9000/g' /etc/nginx/sites-available/peertube
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations, your webserver is already working!

As you've stated you've skipped [peertubes webserver configurations steps](https://docs.joinpeertube.org/install-any-os?id=truck-webserver), you might want to go back to the documentation and follow the steps on how to configure said webserver for peertube.